# Function to check mathematical expression not working

Tags: javascript, stack

The Function to check mathematical expression not working.

I debugged this on chrome, and i saw that when it gets to the first pop (`stack.pop()!== chars[i]`), it returns false, but it shouldn't.

```
var smarter_validate = function(str) {
  var chars = str.split('');
  var stack = [];
  var lookup = {
    '(': ')',
    '[': ']',
    '{': '}',
    '<': '>'
  };
  var left = Object.keys(lookup);
  var right = Object.keys(lookup).map(function(key) {
    return lookup[key]
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (left.indexOf(chars[i]) !== (-1)) {
      stack.push(chars[i]);
    } else if (right.indexOf(chars[i]) !== (-1)) {
      if ((stack.length === 0) || (stack.pop() !== chars[i])) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return (stack.length === 0);
};

console.log("SMART VALIDATE" + smarter_validate('(3+4[*2{6+8}])'));
```

Comment: Expression can be complex, have you considered using eval()?

Comment: @Will the target syntax is apparently much different than JavaScript expression syntax.

Comment: Is the `*2` intentional? It appears that your math syntax is infix, but that's prefix.

Comment: `stack.push(lookup[chars[i]]);`

Comment: THANKS you all :) 
If anyone have a shorter function i would love to know!!

Comment: @Moran Check [this](http://ideone.com/pjw7DZ) out

Comment: @thefourtheye thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually have to compare the popped value's corresponding closing character with `chars[i]`, not the popped value itself.

So you need to do

```
if (stack.length === 0 || lookup[stack.pop()] !== chars[i]) {
```

Now, when you `{` from the stack, you will look for the corresponding closing character from the `lookup` and compare it with the current closing character.

---

Alternatively you can simply push the expected closing character in the stack so that you don't have do the lookup during the comparison, like this

```
stack.push(lookup[chars[i]]);
```